# Distinguishing points from different sources in a ProbabilityScalePlot

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

Is it possible to use `ProbabilityScalePlot` to show different plot markers in a single dataset, such as in going from `plot2` to `plot3` below?

```
nPoints = 10;
x = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 1], nPoints];
y = RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[1, 1], nPoints];
z = RandomVariate[WeibullDistribution[1, 1], nPoints];

plot1 = SmoothHistogram[{x, y, z}, Filling -> Axis]
plot2 = ProbabilityScalePlot[{x, y, z}]
plot3 = ProbabilityScalePlot[Flatten[{x, y, z}]]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3):

```
s = GatherBy[First@Cases[FullForm@plot3, Point[h___] :> h, Infinity], 
             Function[{u}, MemberQ[#, u[[1]]] & /@ {x, y, z}]]

plot3 /. Point[__] :>  MapThread[{#1, Point@#2} &, {{Red, Blue, Green}, s}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I'll have to work on understanding the syntax, but your solution obviously works!  Many thanks.

Comment: @JimLarsen Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

More complicated, but I thought it interesting to see how to generate the plot from first principles:

```
nPoints = 10;
x = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 1], nPoints];
y = RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[1, 1], nPoints];
z = RandomVariate[WeibullDistribution[1, 1], nPoints];
data = {x, y, z};
nn = Length@Flatten[data];
ordereddata = 
   MapIndexed[ {(First@#2 - .3)/(nn + .4), Sequence @@ #1} &, 
       Sort[Join @@ 
          MapIndexed[ Function[{dat, ind}, {#, First@ind} & /@ dat], 
           data ]]];
dataprime = 
   Table[{#[[2]], 1 - Sqrt[2] InverseErfc[2 #[[1]]]} & /@
       Select[ ordereddata , #[[3]] == k &], {k, Length@data}];
Show[ ProbabilityScalePlot[Flatten[data] ],
    ListPlot[dataprime, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}] ]
```

[image]

Note this is drawing the color markers over top of the probabilityplot markers.`ProbabiltyPlotRange` for some reason does not respect `PlotMarkers->None`, but you can hide them with something like `PlotMarkers -> Graphics@{PointSize[0], Point[{0, 0}]}`

Note also this is specific to the default normal distribution assumed by `ProbabilityPlotRange`

Comment: This is exceptional also! What are the odds that Wolfram will add such a capability to the Options for ProbabilityScalePlot sometime in the near future?  I'm surprised the need hasn't arisen before.

Answer (score 1):

```
colorF = Piecewise[{{Red, MemberQ[x, #[[1]]]}, {Green, MemberQ[y, #[[1]]]}}, Blue] &;

Normal[ProbabilityScalePlot[Flatten[{x, y, z}]]] /. 
   Point[p_] :> ({colorF @ #, PointSize[.015], Point @ #} & /@ p)
```

[image]